# Split string by every new instance of a letter

Tags: javascript

Couldn't find anything while searching but I need to split a string by each new instance of a letter. I know split() would output: (M,B,A,M,M,D,X,X,M,M,M,G,G,M,M,Z) but can't figure out how to group them.

Exmaple: "MBAMMDXXMMMGGMMZ" should output to:
M
B
A
MM
D
XX
MMM
GG
MM
Z

```
str = "MBAMMDXXMMMGGMMZ"

newStr = str.split("")
console.log(newStr)
```

Comment: What happened to the question about sorting them by groups, from yesterday? I know it's how SO works, and it's nothing against you, but wow i hate how stuff gets deleted all the time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One regex approach would be to do the following find and replace:

```
Find:    (.)(?!\1)
Replace: $1[ ]
```

This regex pattern will capture each letter which is *not* followed by the same letter, and in that case insert a space after the captured letter:

```
(.)    capture each letter
(?!\1) which is NOT followed by the same letter (i.e. is followed by a different letter)
```

Sample script:

```js
var input = "MBAMMDXXMMMGGMMZ";
var output = input.replace(/(.)(?!\1)/g, "$1 ");
console.log(input + "\n" + output);
```

Comment: Can you explain what the replace function is doing? Not in basic terms but I'm not familiar with the advanced stuff.

Comment: @wayoh22 I have added an explanation to my answer.

Comment: That  makes perfect sense now. I'm not familiar with regex yet but thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to avoid regular expressions you may convert the string into an array and use the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method.

```js
var input = "MBAMMDXXMMMGGMMZ";

Array.from(input).reduce((prev, curr, index, array) => {
  let next;
  if (prev.includes(curr)) {
    // If char matches previous group, add it.
    next = prev + curr;
  } else {
    // If it differs, log previous group and begin a new one.
    console.log(prev);
    next = curr;
  }
  
  // If that's the last iteration, log the final group.
  if (index == array.length - 1) {
    console.log(next);
  }
  
  return next;
});
```

It is also possible to use this method to get an array of grouped string, it just requires changing the console logging to pushing groups into some array.

```js
var input = "MBAMMDXXMMMGGMMZ";
var output = [];

Array.from(input).reduce((prev, curr, index, array) => {
  let next;
  if (prev.includes(curr)) {
    // If char matches previous group, add it.
    next = prev + curr;
  } else {
    // If it differs, add previous group to an output array and begin a new one.
    output.push(prev);
    next = curr;
  }
  
  // If that's the last iteration, push the final group.
  if (index == array.length - 1) {
    output.push(next);
  }
  
  return next;
});

console.log(output);
```

Comment: That's an interesting way to go about it too. I think the above method is better because I inevitably need to convert that string into an array and then sort it by length and then alphabetically sort it

Comment: In this solution you could change the console logging into pushing the groups to an array to gather the results instead of printing them.

Comment: So essentially instead of just using console.log() I could initiate an empty array after "let next" and then just use "nameOfArray.push(next)?

Comment: I've just added a second snippet :)